# question php to django simple loop increasing

Tags: python, django, loops, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I have to convert some php code to python django. In django I noticed that it is difficult to make things like php does.

I have to increase a simple loop by **n ( step) *** iteration,

php code:

```
<?php $step = 3; for($i=0; $i < count($items); $i += $step){ /* */}
```

In django template:

I tried a `for` loop of a dictionary:

```
   data['posts'] = {
    "comments": [
        {"id": "1", "title": "hey buddy"},
        {"id": "2", "title": "hey buddy"},
        {"id": "4", "title": "hey buddy"},
        {"id": "5", "title": "hey buddy"},
        {"id": "6", "title": "hey buddy"},
        {"id": "7", "title": "hey buddy"},
        {"id": "8", "title": "hey buddy"},
        {"id": "9", "title": "hey buddy"},

    ]
}
```

and in template:

```
for elem in posts.items: 
{{ forloop.counter0|add:"3" }}
```

This works, but it is only display, not set the loop counter to each iteration to 3.

I want that each iteration, the loop will increase by a specified number.

**EDIT**
so the result i want in django template is:

```
<div> the first 3 items </div>
<div> the next 3 items (so +3) </div>
<div> the final 3 items (+3) </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved without creating a custom tag in django, just used [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby).

Example:

```
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %} 
    output items divide into 3 groups 
{% endif %}
```